# trying to recover funds from an older ethereum wallet

Tags: ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp, recovery

I downloaded an older version of ethereum wallet in march. and transferred some ether to the account. I have not uploaded in a few months but when i turn on wallet, it refuses to download new blocks.

i downloaded a newer version of wallet, which works fine, but it does not have my original ether.

I have my "UTC" file under keystore directory. I am basically trying to restore my ether to the updated walllet so i can transfer back to coinbase and move back to cash.

any help would be appreciated as I don't have much technical expertise but can figure out most things.

Answer (score 2):

There are some issues with latest version of Mist like [Accounts are not showing up in Mist](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/1308). Don't worry your ethers are safe. I suggest you to first check your balance on [etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io/).

> The reason why you account doesn't show ethers is because the your
>   blockchain is not in sync.

Please wait until your blockchain syncs, your ethers will appear in your account as soon as blockchain syncs.
If you want to move funds immediately, you can use [My Ether wallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/).